# How can I print every list that exists in a JSON file? Python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, list

I was wondering how I could print every list from a JSON file.

```
{
    "Hello" : [
        {
            "A" : "B",
            "C" : [2,2,[1,2,3,4,5]]
        },
        {
            "A" : "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I don't know how to do it. I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: ```[2,2,[1,2,3,4,5]]``` is this the expected output?

Comment: No, ignore it, it's just an example for a list. What I asking is, is there some method to read a JSON file and to get every list/array that exists in this JSON. I don't know if it's possible, but I really need it. Thank you

Comment: What I am asking is: ```[2,2,[1,2,3,4,5]]``` is a list and even ```[
        {
            "A" : "B",
            "C" : [2,2,[1,2,3,4,5]]
        },
        {
            "A" : "B"
        }
    ]``` is a list. Which one do u want?

Comment: @Sushil I need them both. But not specific for this JSON, cause I know how to get it with this simple JSON. I need some method to get every list even if I don't know this list exists.